# Running a java program located at any location from another java program

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime.exec

I am working on a simple java program which runs another java program which is located at any location in the file system. Here is the code:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class CompileTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         try {
                int k = runProcess("javac H://Study//eclipse_workspace//advance//src//Hello.java");
                if (k==0)
                k=runProcess("java H://Study//eclipse_workspace//advance//src//Hello");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

    private static int runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        pro.waitFor();
        //System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
         return pro.exitValue();
    }

    private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Hello.java

```
class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

But when it is compile it give output as:-

```
java H://Study//eclipse_workspace//advance//src//Hello stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class H:..Study..eclipse_workspace..advance..src..Hello
```

I am using Eclipse IDE

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break the `String arg` into `String[] args` since that will provide benefits such as correclty accounting for paths with space characters in them.

Comment: As an aside, given what it is that the code is trying to achieve, see also the [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) which is an *"Interface to invoke Java™ programming language compilers from programs"*. Then create a `URLClassLoader` to load the resulting class from the local file system and call the `main(String[])` method directly. This provides not only simpler programming, but also better feedback from either the compiliation or execution phases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like: `java -classpath . Hello`.
If you didn't specified package you must run `Hello.class` from the same directory.

`runProcess(cd H:/Study/eclipse_workspace/advance/src/)`

And then

`runProcess(java Hello)`

Comment: Hello.java and CompilerTest.java is in the same directory @LeonidLunin

Comment: @AbhishekThakur try to cd in this directory before run java Hello

Comment: no its not working
'java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)'

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)

these Exceptions are coming @LeonidLunin